# Android: TextView Not working

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm new to android deva and java. I want to display text but my code below does not work.

**DisplayText.java**

```
package com.example.DisplayText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayText extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.thetext);
            tv2.setText("YO -- ");
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
    }
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/thetext"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Many thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You need to specify which layout file you want to use before you can get any Views from it. In your code above you are trying to fetch a TextView before the call setContentView. This will not work since there is no indication for the system of where to look for TextView with ID theText. If you change the order and set the content view first it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.thetext);
            tv2.setText("YO -- ");
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
```

with this one:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.thetext);
            tv2.setText("YO -- ");


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

put

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before `TextView tv2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.thetext);`

to access the TextView from main.xml